# React routing appears slows and error page not showing

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to get more familiar with reactjs routing. I've built this small demo - but the application appears slow in switching between pages and also the error page doesn't show when the url is wrong.

http://localhost:3000/ -- goes to home

http://localhost:3000/about  -- goes to about (but feels slow to render)

http://localhost:3000/abc  -- goes to home instead of the error - why?

structure looks like this

```
my-app
├── build
│   └── static_
│   └── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── node_modules_
├── .gitignore
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── components
    │    ├── About
    │    │    └── About.js
    │    ├── Error
    │    │    └── Error.js
    │    ├── Header
    │    │    └── Header.js
    │    └── Home
    │        └── Home.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    └── router.js
```

// index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import './index.css'

import Routes from './router'

// this is a class because it needs state
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes />
    )
  }
}

render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

// Router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

// components
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import About from './components/About/About'
import Error from './components/Error/Error'

import Header from './components/Header/Header'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

// we can pass the lang files as props to the routes
// we should have a nested route inside service here to show the other services page

class Routes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className='off-canvas-wrap' data-offcanvas>
            <div className='inner-wrap'>
              <Header transparent />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                <Redirect from='/' />
                <Route component={Error} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes
```

// About.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// this is a class because it needs state
class About extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        About
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default About
```

// Error.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// this is a class because it needs state
class Error extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        Error
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Error
```

// Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Menu, Icon, Alert } from 'antd'

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

// this is a class because it needs state
class Header extends Component {

  state = {
    current: 'home',
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
        mode="horizontal"
      >
        <Menu.Item key="home">
          <Link to="/home" rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="about">
          <Link to="/about" rel="noopener noreferrer">About</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

// Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// this is a class because it needs state
class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        Home
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: I've put the code base in this jsfiddle as reference -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/102/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are actually reloading the page and rerendering the app every time you click on an anchor(`<a>`) tag. The idea behind a Single Page Application is that you do not reload the page because otherwise all internal data would be lost.

My advice would be to look into [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) for routing in your application: It's the industry standard for routing in react. It's fairly simple to use and takes care of these sorts of things.

As far as the Error page thing goes, I can't tell because your most important file in this regard (`router.js`) is missing.

Edit: Ah, I see now that you have added it, ad also that you are using react-router. You should use `react-router`'s `Link` component instead of anchor tags.

```
    <Menu.Item key="home">
      <Link to="/home" rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="about">
      <Link to="/about" rel="noopener noreferrer">About</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
```

The reason your error page is not showing is that you are redirecting before react-router get's the chance to render the error page. If you remove this redirect it should work:

```
    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route component={Error} />
```

Comment: -- I've just added in the router.js -- but I'm using "react-router-dom"?

Comment: ok - that did speed it up - swapping out the <a> for the <Link>  - what was going on there? But the error page doesn't show when the url is wrong.

Comment: @TheOldCounty The answer to that is in the first paragraph of my answer. The error page is not showing because you are redirecting to "/" instead of showing the error when you are on an invalid link.

Comment: I took out the "<Redirect from='/' />" it still doesn't show the error page

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache, maybe it cached the redirect?

Comment: No I don't think its that. Is there a way to show this as demo

Comment: any other ideas as to why its not going to the error page -- is there a way to mock this up in a jsfiddle - give it a test -

Comment: any ideas on what would cause an error page to not load -- why would it assume home?

Comment: it is because of this  <Route path='/' component={Home} />  -- this is what's causing the error page not to show -- because really I should have it like this  <Route exact  path='/' component={Home} />